# PhpStorm ignore settings files and folders

Tags: github, ide, phpstorm

I'm having some trouble with PhpStorm 2016. For some reason, every time I close the application, a bunch of settings files get pushed onto my GitHub. Here's a screenshot of some of the xml files that get pushed, including `_windows` folder and inspection `folder`. You can see that these files get mixed with my actual web application files and when pulling from git, these files get pulled also.

Is there any way to not have this happen all the time? Every time I delete these files, they miraculously re-appear in my git. I don't think ignoring these files is the remedy to this though.
[image]

My `.gitignore` has the following:

```
# Created by .ignore support plugin (hsz.mobi)
### JetBrains template
# Covers JetBrains IDEs: IntelliJ, RubyMine, PhpStorm, AppCode, PyCharm, CLion, Android Studio and Webstorm
# Reference: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839

# User-specific stuff:
.idea/workspace.xml
.idea/tasks.xml
.idea/dictionaries
.idea/vcs.xml
.idea/jsLibraryMappings.xml

# Sensitive or high-churn files:
.idea/dataSources.ids
.idea/dataSources.xml
.idea/dataSources.local.xml
.idea/sqlDataSources.xml
.idea/dynamic.xml
.idea/uiDesigner.xml

# Gradle:
.idea/gradle.xml
.idea/libraries

# Mongo Explorer plugin:
.idea/mongoSettings.xml

## File-based project format:
.iws

## Plugin-specific files:

# IntelliJ
/out/

# mpeltonen/sbt-idea plugin
.idea_modules/

# JIRA plugin
atlassian-ide-plugin.xml

# Crashlytics plugin (for Android Studio and IntelliJ)
com_crashlytics_export_strings.xml
crashlytics.properties
crashlytics-build.properties
fabric.properties
```

Which works fine for the `.idea` folder. Any ideas?

Comment: Not enough data .. but so far it looks like misconfigured "Settings Repository" plugin

Comment: Misconfigure settings repo. I'll have to check that out... Have you ever seen these files before?

Comment: Those are IDE-wide config files (at least most of the file names matches). On Windows 7+ you can find them at `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\.PhpStorm%VERSION%\config\options`

Comment: Okay. I'm curious to know why these settings would find themselves here. I've seen on a few Git repos the same files but under a different folder.

Comment: Ask developers of that plugin + check your configuration. I have seen such cases before .. but I still cannot tell *for sure* who's fault is that -- devs (bad defaults or bug) or user (misconfiguration, mainly carelessness). But based on those cases it's leaning towards "user's fault" side.

Comment: Great. I'll into it some more! Thanks for the input!

Comment: As for "I've seen on a few Git repos the same files but under a different folder." part -- most likely they were in `.idea` folder -- those are project-specific settings and can be included in VCS (at least most of them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you have set up the Settings Repository plugin to use the same URL as your project git repository (check the URL in File | Settings Repository). The plugin automatically synchronizes the local IDE settings on exiting WebStorm/closing the project, making the xml files appear in your Git repository

Comment: You mean the Upstream URL? Is that suppose to be some local location?

Comment: it's supposed to be URL of upstream Git repository. You can specify a file path there, you will be prompted to init repository if specified path does not exists or repository is not created

Comment: Okay, because the current URL that's in there is a remote GitHub URL location from an old project, hence why the settings are being 'pulled' from that project. Is it this: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/10.0/sharing-your-ide-settings.html  that you're referring to?